# How can I get my PDF to open in Adobe Reader by clicking a link in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am really having some problems in that I want my visitors to open a certain PDF from a link on my site, however, I can get it to display on a separate tab next to my website, but what I would really like is for it to be forced to open in Adobe Reader.
Is this possible? Has anyone managed to do this?

I have my links set up, they open in a separate tab, but I just feel its more professional if it were to open in Adobe Reader.

Comment: You can't control how a random computer opens a link clicked on your web site. Besides, if you did this, how would you handle somebody who doesn't have Adobe Reader installed?

Comment: Deciding which application to use for a specific file type is a function of the browser itself.  You could send header information to indicate that the file should be downloaded rather than opened, but the browser controls anything beyond that.

Comment: Ahh, okay, thanks though. 
So, really the best way forward is that the user can just open the PDF in a new tab? 
Then they can just print and view I guess?
Thanks for the reply there.
Daz.

Comment: Is my above comment correct would you say? In that it can only be viewed in a separate tab?

Comment: As others have mentioned, you could have the user download the pdf when they click the link.  The download dialog usually gives the user the option to either save the file to disk or open it.  The user will always choose which program to open the file with.  Forcing people to use Adobe is a bad idea... there are lots of people who don't have/want Adobe Reader on their computer (including me).

Answer (score 2):

Ive been looking for the same thing, and the answer is very simple : add download to your a href code : `< a href="document.pdf" download>`

It prompts a box which asks you if you want to save or just open the document

Comment: I tried it, it works great, and better yet, from Chrome the link opens up Adobe Acrobat automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it work, but its not working for msedge. I've set default pdf to be opened from acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the browser will detect that the link with holds a .pdf, and it will open up the PDF in the browsers viewer, and I have seen this in just about all browsers. Then you will be able to use the given functions like size, print, and save.